# the usage of "by"

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs, time, adverbial-phrases

> As a result, we'll be pushing back the interviews for the executive assistant position - including the one scheduled for you on Tuesday - **by** one day.

What does the "by" mean in this sentence?
I guess it means the interview might be held on Wednesday instead of Tuesday.
Am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. The construction used here is *push back by one/some hour(s)/day(s)/etc*.

*push back by one day* means *make something happen a day later*.

This construction has an antonym - *push forward*.